# -network UNCLAIMED description: Network controller product: RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter

Tags: drivers, wireless, upgrade, network-manager, realtek-wireless

After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10, my wifi not showing up.

---

Output of following command

```
sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: b4:b6:86:0f:79:a1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Comment: You probably installed some drivers on the previous version and they aren't supported by the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this result after some googling: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/install-rtl8188eu-rtl8723ds-drivers-ppa-ubuntu-20-04/

Though this guide says it's for 20.04, [the PPA page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/kablosuz/+index?field.series_filter=&batch=75&memo=75&start=75) suggests that this PPA works for Impish (21.10) too.

Connect to the internet via ethernet, which seems to be working according to your `lshw`, and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8723de-dkms
```

Comment: followed your instruction by letter and everything installed perfectly but wifi did n't  work, though i have disable secure boot and follow the "modprobe" command line. see if you can still help me. I can't share the result of your instructions for there is a limit on characters.