# No wired ethernet connection detected on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

I have an ubuntu 20.04 server. When installing I connected an ethernet cable to the motherboard ethernet port. I know for a fact that the internet cable is OK, as I have a different server, which connects like it should

**Relevant information**

`$ lspci | grep -i eth` yields:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
```

`$ sudo lshw -c network` yields:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 04
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff memory:a1110000-a1113fff
```

`$ ip addr`:

```
1L lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface eth0 lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
```

I have tried several options ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233934/no-internet-connection-after-ubuntu-server-20-04-install-ifconfig-not-available), [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240325/ethernet-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-server-20-04), [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370256/network-unclaimed-description-network-controller-product-rtl8723de-802-11b-g) and [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328687/no-ethernet-link-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04-for-unknown-reason)) but none are working for me.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel did not support my ethernet adapter by default. Downloading the drivers from [here](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) (the 2.5G linux driver) and trying to install that resulted in multiple errors about missing packages. These could not be easily installed (I wasn't able to at least). So I figured I should write a step by step guide for others experiencing the same problems as I did.

**Step 1: (Download kernel files)**

I downloaded the following files in order to upgrade the kernel:

```
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_all.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-modules-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb
```

Then move to a USB drive (remember, we don't have the convenience of internet to do everything for us...)

example folder structure: `D:/kernel/`

You should have 4 files in the kernel folder on your usb drive.

**Step 2: (Mount USB)**

- Create a folder for mounting your USB: `$ mkdir /media/usb`
- Find USB drive address: `$ lsblk`
- Mount USB drive in folder: `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb` (my USB drive's address was `sdb1`)

**Step 3: (Install new kernel)**

To install:

Move to the kernel folder

```
$ cd /media/usb/kernel
```

And install the new kernel:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**Step 4: (find ethernet interface)**

If all has gone well as it did for me you should find a new interface when running the following command: `$ ip a`

For a more detailed guide on this, please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240325/ethernet-does-not-work-with-ubuntu-server-20-04)

Hope it helped!

*Mind you, switching to the HWE stack kernel will severely limit LTE support, as they only come with 6 months worth of security updates.*

If ^ this is a problem for you, you could download the missing packages for installing the required driver from realtek, then [downgrade the kernel to the standard version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310622/downgrade-to-kernel-5-4-0-because-kernel-5-8-45-doesnt-like-my-bluetooth-contro) and subsequently install the driver from a usb stick now that you have the required packages.