# Ubuntu Server 20.04 cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking, drivers, server, kernel, ethernet

My freshly installed Ubuntu Server couldn't detect ethernet device or wifi device, there was only loopback in `ip a`. This is what I tried:

1. Tried Ubuntu Server 22.04, and found that my ethernet and wifi works well in that kernel version, no problem connect to internet.
2. Install back Ubuntu Server 20.04 with default kernel 5.4, neither ethernet nor wifi hardware detected in `ip a`
3. Follow this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1382610/1603518) to upgrade to kernel 5.9, ethernet device was detected without connection. `ip link` returns loopback and this:

```
2: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7c:16:23:24:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
```

Additional information:

1. Current kernel version: 5.9.0-050900-generic
2. Result from `lspci` (I will only give whichever relevant, as I am typing it out) :

```
   Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (17) I219-LM (rev 11)
   Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
```

Does it means my hardware still not supported in kernel 5.9? What should I do to solve this? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: "Does it means my hardware still not supported in kernel 5.9?" That is correct. Your device is supported in kernel versions 5.15 and later. "What should I do to solve this?" Go back to Ubuntu 22.04.